# Is there a way to not expose ASP.NET Core Identity pages

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I have a Blazor Wasm hosted application. To authenticate/authorize the client I use `Identity` (not `IdentityServer`) UI with `OpeIddict`. They work nicely together. The only problem I have is limiting `Identity` only to allow `Login` and `Register`. At the same time, there is also a possibility of managing an account and I would like to forbid that and do that on blazor side.

How can I achieve that? Or is there a possibility to use Blazor UI for login/register?

Comment: Hi @hasrthur, do you mean you want to forbid default Identity Login/Register and Manage Account? But maintain the other function in Identity?

Comment: There are actually two questions: 1) can I allow only login/register ui from identity and forbid anything else identity has to offer?; 2) can I change default login/register ui to use blazor components?

Comment: Hi @hasrthur, 1) you can do not use anything else in Identity but cannot forbid. 2) of course you can design by yourself.